# Extending adminhtml controller from another module in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, controllers, extend

this is my config.xml from my module:

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mynamespace_mymodule> before="Adyen_Subscription_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mynamespace_mymodule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

This is my controller from my module:

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Adyen_Subscription'). DS .'Adminhtml'. DS .'SubscriptionController.php';
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_SubscriptionAddressController extends Adyen_Subscription_Adminhtml_SubscriptionController
{
    public function updateSubscriptionAction()
    {
echo 1; exit();
    }
...
}
```

This is the path to the controller that I want to extends:

```
app/code/community/Adyen/Subscription/controllers/Adminhtml/SubscriptionController.php
```

Im not getting the `echo 1; exit();` Any idea what did I do wrong ? 
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a breaking > in your config.

Change:

```
<mynamespace_mymodule> before="Adyen_Subscription_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mynamespace_mymodule>
```

To

```
<mynamespace_mymodule before="Adyen_Subscription_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mynamespace_mymodule>
```

See if this will fix your issue.